# Questions on changing from WinForms to WPF

Tags: mvvm

I have recently been looking for a way to bind data in WinForms using MVVM.
I ended up creating a custom implementation of the MVVM pattern.
However, due to the lack of two-way binding, I have decided to give WPF a try.

I already have the Model, which encapsulates the non-ui functionality. For example the Model reads a configuration file, has a few properties, listens for incoming data on a socket, and saves incoming packets if needed.
Some of the Model's properties throws an exception if they are set out of range. I.e. the validation is done in the Model.

How is validation usually done in WPF? I have read a good deal of articles, and there seems to be some consistency in putting validation in the ViewModel. In fact, most articles only use ViewModel and View. Has the Model been buried?

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see your decision to move away from custom implementations of MVVM when so much already exists that just ... works.

WPF is very strong for two way binding and that gives it its' greatest strengths.

The view model is bound to the view and acts as the mechanism to communicate with the data layer.  Also Entity Framework (if you are on framework 4.0) will give you a great data layer for populating your entities in your ViewModel.  This basically becomes your Model.  It gives you an encapsulated form of UnitOfWork as well as Repository patterns.

While your view model in all examples are usually on a one-to-one basis, if the design calls for it you can have view models that span multiple views.  I have a "menu" which displays key identifiers from each item in the list and a detail form that shows all fields for editing from the same object.  So I span the view between the two.

You can hard code the view model in the xaml binding it to the datacontext or you can use Unity and inject the viewmodel into the view.  Unfortunately the injection requires adding one public property for the purpose of setting the datacontext.  So you'd have code like this:

```
public class MyView:Window
{
     public MyView(MyViewModel model)
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         ViewModel = model;
     }
     public MyViewModel ViewModel
     {
         set{ this.DataContext = value; }
     }
}
```

So the rest is just TwoWay binding for each field and the setter can encapsulate single value editing.  Your error message can even be bound to a text field on the form and it displays when the value is not null.

Also if you dig into Unity you will also get a truly great function called Event Aggregation which basically provides a vehicle for publish/subscribe of events and that ties into your ICommand implementation when getting a button click handled.